# Stored Procedure: Update or Insert data between two databases on the same mysql server

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, phpmyadmin, mariadb, insert-update

I am trying to create a procedure to Insert or update data into a user table in a different database on the same MariaDB server. I am using phpMyAdmin.

I have the following two tables:

```
Database 1: members
    Table: tbl_members_contacts
        ContactTypeID INT (11)
        MemberID INT (11)
        ContactInfo VARCHAR (255)

Indexes:    
    Primary Unique  MemberID + ContactTypeID
    ContactInfo Unique
    

Database 2: members_sec
    Table: sec_users
        login INT (11)
        email VARCHAR (255)
Indexes:    
    Primary Unique  login
```

I only want to update data from the table on Database 1 when the ContactTypeID = 1, which is the member's email address. If no security records exist for the member in Database 2, I need to insert a new record.

I will use an update and insert trigger to call the procedure when the data in the table in the Database are added or changed.

The Procedure which I tried to make on Database 1:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sec_usersUpdate()
BEGIN
    IF tbl_members_contacts.ContactTypeID = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO members_sec.sec_users
        (login, email)
        VALUES
        (tbl_members_contacts.MemberID, tbl_members_contacts.ContactInfo)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        members_sec.sec_users.login = VALUES(tbl_members_contacts.MemberID),
        members_sec.sec_users.email = VALUES(tbl_members_contacts.ContactInfo);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I receive the following message when I try to run the query on Database 1:

MySQL said:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
END' at line 11

I have never tried to make a procedure before, so I am maybe far off. I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: You are using mariadb, not mysql. You would have to use the NEW/OLD keywords instead of the table name in the if condition to refer to the current record the trigger affects. But I do not know if that will work in a stored proc. You may have to do this in the trigger body.

Comment: Why do you add a semicolon behind `END IF` but not behind `INSERT ....` ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter Thanks, should be, edited in the question but with the same result.

Comment: @Shadow Thank you. Yes, I know it's a MariaDB, which I thought should be 100 Compatible with MySQL. Every time I search for MariDB solutions I mostly get MySQL responses and Error messages still state "MySQL said: #1064". I have changed the Question. I tried to make a trigger the first time with no success. I will try the trigger solution again.

Comment: Mariadb's non-compliance with mysql list is over 17 pages long, so it is definitely not 100 compatible with mysql. To all intents and purposes you must treat it as a different product from mysql.

Comment: @Shadow As I said, I thought.... ;-)

Comment: I now think the problem is that tbl_members_contacts.MemberID is not Unique in it selves, but only together with tbl_members_contacts. ContactTypeID. INSERT INTO need a UNIQUE CONSTRAIN.